# id and tags is removed after jQuery load

Tags: javascript, jquery

FILE: a.html

```
...
// JavaScript function
function abc( id )
{
  $("#body").load( "b.html" );

  var m = document.getElementById( "bbb" );
  // id and tag is removed after load, bbb can not be found. m is null
  if (m != null)
  {
    m.innerText = "XYZ";
  }
}

...
// HTML
<div id="body">

</div>
```

FILE: b.html

```
<div id="bbb" tag="bbb" onclick="DoOnClick()">
</div>
```

**tag** and **id** is removed after jQuery.load. 
How can i keep id or tag after load ?

Comment: `load()` is async, use the complete callback  http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function

Comment: Adding to ^^^ `$("#body").load( "b.html", function() { var m = document.getElementById( "bbb" ); // } );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like that - [LOAD](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed.

```
function abc( id )
{
  $("#body").load( "b.html",function(){

      var m = document.getElementById( "bbb" );
      // id and tag is removed after load, bbb can not be found. m is null
      if (m != null)
       {
         m.innerText = "XYZ";
       }

  });

}
```